# Building an array from a static array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

EDIT:

I have the following:

```
$EXCLUDE['extensions']="199";
$EXCLUDE['extensions']="800-1000":
```

What I want to do is be able to create a list of values, either single digit or a range.

End result:

I have this(listed below) and I want to replace the 799 and 1000 with what I have below and set it so that it DOES NOT display those extensions if they contain those numbers. But I also want to include a range as well.

```
foreach($obj as $file) {
                    if($file['dir_list']=="yes"){
                        if($file['user']<="799" || $file['user']>="1000"){
                    $D = $domain;
                    $V = $file['user'];
                    $g = $this->get_presence($D,$V);
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand. It might be easier if you tell us what you're starting with (how you get your values) and what you want to end up with, by providing a very concrete example of an input and expected output

Comment: The code you've shown where you create the `$EXCLUDE` array sets the `extensions` key to `199` and then overwrites it with `800-1000`. Was this a typo? Did you mean to append to that key instead?

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Yes, I want append values and ranges into one single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a 2-dimensional array of start/end values.

```
$exclude = array(
    array('start' => 199, 'end' => 199),
    array('start' => 800, 'end => 1000)
);
```

Then iterate over the array to see if the value is in on of the excluded ranges.

```
foreach ($obj as $file) {
    $excluded = false;
    foreach ($exclude as $e) {
        $num = intval($file['user']);
        if ($num >= $e['start'] && $num <= $e['end']) {
            $excluded = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$excluded) {
        $D = $domain;
        $V = $file['user'];
        $g = $this->get_presence($D, $V);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I've understood the question correctly, but here it is:
The initialization of an array can be done with [array()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), for example:

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 5, "foo", 8, 19, "some text", "foo");
?>
```

This creates an array with seven elements. As you can see, types within an array can be mixed.

Values that you put in an array must neither be array nor come from arrays, but it is allowed. The following code creates an array of arrays:

```
<?php
//array of arrays
$a = array(
           array(1,2,3),
           array("test", "text"),
           array(1,2,"foo")
);
?>
```